# zend 1 xsd validation

Tags: xml, zend-framework, xsd-validation

I am building a simple API end-point in ZF1 and got to the stage of XML validation. I could not find it anywhere in Zend documentation, so maybe someonehas come accross this before: Does Zend Framework 1 has any kind of library or wrapper for validating XML against XSD? or is using DOMDocument the only available solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not provide anything, but there is no reason as you can use PHP's DomDocument class to perform this validation and it is a very simple task:

```
 $dom= new \DomDocument();
 $dom->loadXML($xmlContent);
 $dom->schemaValidate('xsd/schema.xsd');
```

I would use this code to build a custom validator, so it's easy to reuse:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html

Comment: I have updated the answer with a comment on custom validator, hope that helps @Auris